# Excel calculate median with values occurences in other row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate median from, let's say: 1,1,2,2,3. If the values are specified like that, it is pretty easy, just by selecting the cells. But what if I have these values specified within two rows, when one row is 1,2,3 (possible values) and the other row defines occurrences (in this case 2,2,1 because 1 comes two times, 2 comes two times, 3 comes one time)

```
1 2 3 (values)
2 2 1 (occurences)
```

In other words, I need a way to "multiply" the values in a way, that 2 times 1 give 1,1 etc.

Comment: I'm not following what you trying to archive. Can can specify what " 2 times 1 give 1" means?

Comment: @VBAPete looks like occurrences/observation indicates the frequency for each *value*, so in all observations, there is 1 instance of "3", and 2 instances of "1" and 2 instances of "2".

Comment: @DavidZemens Got that part, but what is kjdkfjsdo8 trying to multiply? All values multiplied by their occurrences?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend reshaping the data personally, it beats an ugly implementation of repeat() and string manipulation.

Comment: OP not actually trying to "multiply" anything, just using bad terminology.

Comment: VBA is going to be your best answer.  Formulas are going to require at least two helper rows to create the array properly.

Comment: David stated it correctly. Imagine you have three possible answers 10$,20$,30$ (one row: 10,20,30) and 3 people answered a, 3 people answered b, 1 person answered c (second row: 3,3,1)
Now to calculate median I need values in form 10,10,10,20,20,20,30, but I don't know how to get it from these two rows.